# Not Found Apache/2.2.3 (Debian), what does it mean?

Tags: spam-prevention

Found this in a spammer comment:

Not Found Apache/2.2.3 (Debian) mod_python/3.2.10 Python/2.4.4 PHP/5.2.0-8+etch15 mod_ssl/2.2.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8c Server at allhomedecor.org Port 80 404 Not Found The requested URL /forxru2/zadanie.txt was not found on this server.

Does it mean they hack an other server (allhomedecor.org) to do their spam ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the normal Apache Server error message for a [404 (page not found)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) http status. In your example the file /forxu2/zadanie.txt wasn't found. [Check it out yourself](http://allhomedecor.org/forxru2/zadanie.txt).

So this is just a standard error message and has nothing to do with getting hacked.

Comment: Yeah but why this spammer does do this ?

Comment: Well I'm still not sure about Spammers reasons in general. To confuse people maybe? Maybe the spammer tried to insert an automated message file (from /forxru2/zadanie.txt) and got the error message back instead, because the file didn't exist.